# How to fix TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a coding challenge from my teacher and for some reason i can't get these last few lines of code to work before i implement custom string inputs for the user to add their own string.

I have tried changing coding type completely but still wont work and i run into the same issue each and every time.

```
import string 
strg = "peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers. a peck of pickeled 
peppers peter piper picked. if piper piper picked a peck of pickeled 
peppers, wheres the peck of pickled peppers peter piper picked"

for i in range (0, len (strg)):
    if str[i] in ('.'):  
        count = count + 1;
    if str[i] in (','):  
        count2 = count2 + 1;
    if str[i] in ('?'):  
        count3 = count3 + 1;
    if str[i] in ('!'):  
        count4 = count4 + 1;

print ("Total number of full stops string: ");  
print (count);
```

I am hoping for it to output: `Total number of full stops string:x`
however it is currently outputting.

Comment: where have you defined count? and could you provide a full trace of the error?

Comment: you have variable `strg` (with char `g` at the end) but later you use `str` without `g`

Comment: There are many errors here, but this particular one is just because your variable is `strg`, not `str`.

Comment: instead of `for i in range (0, len (strg)):` you can use `for char in strg:` and later you can use `if char in '.':` or `if char == '.':`

Comment: Thanks for the response, the code now works and i am moving on to the next but, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You accidentally used 'str' as the string name instead of strg

```
count = count2 = count3 = count4 = 0

strg = '''peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers. a peck of pickeled 
peppers peter piper picked. if piper piper picked a peck of pickeled 
peppers, wheres the peck of pickled peppers peter piper picked'''

for i in range (0, len (strg)):
    if strg[i] in ('.'):  
        count = count + 1;
    if strg[i] in (','):  
        count2 = count2 + 1;
    if strg[i] in ('?'):  
        count3 = count3 + 1;
    if strg[i] in ('!'):  
        count4 = count4 + 1;


print ("Total number of full stops string: ");  
print (count);
```